# tastypie : return reponse in xml format

Tags: django, tastypie

I read from the documentation that XML format is supported
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html#to-xml, however in current task, I only have to type http://url/api/entry/?format=json in browser and define the correspond url in URL.py and the entry resource, the serialization of json is well taken care of. But for xml, there are extra things to do as I couldnt seem to find useful examples?

```
#urls.py
entry_resource = EntryResource()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(entry_resource.urls)),
)

#entry class
class EntryResource(Resource):
....
....fields

class Meta:
    resource_name = 'entry'
    object_class = Entry
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML format should work out of the box as well. You should be able to see it when you make a following request:

```
GET http://url/api/entry/?format=xml
```

If that doesn't seem to work, then there is a mistake somewhere, but without more details (e.g. your Resource definitions) we won't be able to help.

**UPDATE:**

[Tastypie documentation on Serialization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html#serialization) has a list of formats supported out of the box.

Comment: I did try that but it says properlyConfigured at /api/v1/entry/
Usage of the XML aspects requires lxml. So lxml lib is what is missing..Thought something is wrong with how I defined resource.

Comment: Looking at your pasted source the indentation is wrong, but perhaps it's just a result of copy-paste? Also are you sure lxml installed properly? It takes some time to compile and it may happen that there is an error somewhere towards the end. This however does not concern tastypie per se. Once you get your XML straight it should work. As to resources, please try to simplify them and make sure they follow the syntax...

Comment: And now that you have pasted the code example I see that your resource is not derived from ModelResource class. So for serialization to work you need to make sure that "Entry" objects are serializable. If JSON works however, XML should as well... Could you please paste the full error traceback you're getting ?

Comment: If the answer helped you, you could "choose" it, this helps build my reputation... and is nice reward for the effort put in answering your question...